# Page curl with view pager

Tags: android, opengl-es, android-viewpager, page-curl

I have to implement **page curl** with **Viewpager** so that when user swipe the layouts added to the view pager have the page curling effect. I have downloaded [github.com/harism/android_page_curl](http://github.com/harism/android_page_curl) but it seems like it works only for images as do most of the other implementations.. Can anyone please tell me a workaround of it so that I can perform a page curl with the views I have added to the view pager? Thank you.

Comment: why do you need that, if you explain it can be clearer how to help ?

Comment: did u achieve this??? me too stuck with this..

Answer (score 0):

This [link](https://code.google.com/p/android-page-curl/) will help you out. You can use Page curl in a fragment within the view pager.

Answer (score 0):

you can use this link https://github.com/MysticTreeGames/android-page-curl

i hope this help you